# 'Refresh' Ubuntu Core ssh keys

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-one, snap, ubuntu-core

I have already done the initial console-conf for a DragonBoard 410c using only one key in my Ubuntu SSO account. I would like to refresh those keys that are allowed on the board.

I have tried just logining in assuming it would refresh the keys for me but it doesn't appear to auto refresh.

If possible, I would like to avoid re-imaging the device to just load the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug with Ubuntu Core, detailed here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/snapd/+bug/1646559

There's currently no simple workaround.